# Hourly log4net RollingFileAppender

Tags: configuration, log4net

Is it possible to configure log4net to roll files each hour? If not - any hints on how to override RollingFileAppender with required functionality to make HourlyRollingFileAppender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: set the `datePattern` element's value  to `"yyyyMMdd-HH"`

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="logfile" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />

  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd-HH" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Ref: [log4net Config Examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).