# How to generate hourly based log file in asp.net core log4net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net-configuration

I am using the following code but it never creates a new hourly based log file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4net>
   <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
         <conversionPattern value="C:\ATSApiLog\APILog_%date{yyyyMMdd-HH}.log" />
      </file>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss,fff}, %message%newline" />
      </layout>
   </appender>
   <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
   </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/a/8558416/7124761

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Its working fine in asp.net mvc but now Its not working in asp.net core application